# Differentiability of $z=f(x,y)$ at $(a,b)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

According to my professor, if $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist near $(a,b)$ and are continuous at $(a,b)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$. What does he mean by "exists near $(a,b)$"? Can we say that if $f_x = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$, then it exists near $(a,b)$, but is not continuous at $(a,b)$?.

Furthermore, he says that "it's possible that $f$ is differentiable, while $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist near $(a,b)$ but are not continuous at $(a,b)$". However, he also says that "if $f$ is not continuous at $(a,b)$, then $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$. **Therefore** $f$ is not differentiable at $(a,b)$". I'm not sure what the "therefore" means. Is it

(i) if $f$ is not continuous at $(a,b)$, then $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$ **and** $f$ is not differentiable at $(a,b)$

(ii) if $f$ is not continuous at $(a,b)$, then $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$. If $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$ **then** $f$ is not differentiable at $(a,b)$.

(ii) does not make sense to me since we claimed previously that a function can be differentiable at point while its partial derivatives are not continuous at that point.

Comment: That $g$ exists near $(a,b)$ in this context means that $g$ exists in a neighborhood of $(a,b)$. So there is some $r>0$ such that $g(x,y)$ exists when $\lVert (x,y)-(a,b)\rVert<r$.

Comment: (ii) is obviously wrong, but (i) also: replace "and" by "or" in "$f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist near $(a,b)$ means that there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $(a,b)$ such that $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist in all points of $U$. This amounts to the existence of a number $r > 0$ such that $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist for all $(a',b')$ with $\lVert (a',b') - (a, b) \rVert < r$. Note this includes the existence of $f_x$ and $f_y$ at $(a,b)$.

It is well-known that if $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$, then $f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$ and $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist at $(a,b)$.

> It is possible that $f$ is differentiable, while $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist near $(a,b)$ but are not continuous at $(a,b)$

I guess he wanted to say "$f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$". This is correct.

> If $f$ is not continuous at $(a,b)$, then $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$. **Therefore** $f$ is not differentiable at $(a,b)$.

**Therefore** is not a consequence of the discontinuity of $f_x$ and $f_y$ at $(a,b)$, it is a consequence of the discontinuity of $f$ at $(a,b)$. Hence the interpretation (ii) is false; this is what you say.

Saying that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$ first of all requires *their existence* in an open neigborhood of $(a,b)$. But it is wrong to claim that both $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$. They cannot both be continuous because this would imply that $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ and hence continuous at $(a,b)$. We can only say that at least one of $f_x$ and $f_y$ is not continuous at $(a,b)$.